# Choco install issue with chocolateyinstall.ps1 or nuspec file

Tags: chocolatey

I am trying to create a Chocolatey package and was able to "choco pack" and "choco push" to a local chocolatey.server (simple server) repository. I have configured my `C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\config\chocolatey.config` to point to my local chocolatey.server URL. When I try to run

```
choco install test1
```

I get the following error:

> The package test1 wants to run 'chocolateyinstall.ps1'. Note: If you
>   don't run this script, the installation will fail. Note: To confirm
>   automatically next time, use '-y' or consider setting
>   'allowGlobalConfirmation'. Run 'choco feature -h' for more details. Do
>   you want to run the script?([Y]es/[N]o/[P]rint): Y
>
> ERROR: Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'file' is specified
>   more than once. To provide multiple values to parameters that can
>   accept multiple v alues, use the array syntax. For example,
>   "-parameter value1,value2,value3". The install of nimatest was NOT
>   successful. Error while running
>   'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\test1\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
>   See log for details.
>
> Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.  See the log for
>   details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
>
> Failures
>    - test1 (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\test1\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
>   See log for details.

In my test.nuspec I have the following:

```
<files>
  <!-- This section controls what actually gets packaged into the Chocolatey package -->
  <file src="tools*" target="tools" />
  <!-- Building from Linux? You may need this instead: <file src="tools/*" target="tools" /> -->
</files>
```

In my chocolateyinstall.ps1 I have:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';
$packageName= 'Test1'
$toolsDir = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
$fileLocation = Join-Path $toolsDir 'Test1.exe'

$packageArgs = @{
  packageName = $packageName
  fileType = 'exe'
  file = $fileLocation
  silentArgs = "/SP"
  validExitCodes= @(0, 3010, 1641)
  softwareName = 'Test1*'
  checksum = ''
  checksumType = 'md5'
  checksum64 = ''
  checksumType64 = 'md5'
}

Install-ChocolateyPackage @packageArgs
```

Comment: In my test.nuspec I have the following:     <files>
    <!-- this section controls what actually gets packaged into the Chocolatey package -->
    <file src="tools\**" target="tools" />
    <!--Building from Linux? You may need this instead: <file src="tools/**" target="tools" />-->
  </files>

Comment: In my chocolateyinstall.ps1  I have:  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; 

$packageName= 'Test1' 
$toolsDir   = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
$fileLocation = Join-Path $toolsDir 'Test1.exe'

$packageArgs = @{
  packageName   = $packageName
  fileType      = 'exe' 
  file         = $fileLocation
  silentArgs = "/SP"
  validExitCodes= @(0, 3010, 1641)
  softwareName  = 'Test1*' 
  checksum      = ''
  checksumType  = 'md5'
  checksum64    = ''
  checksumType64= 'md5' }
Install-ChocolateyPackage @packageArgs

Comment: Can you move these comments up to the question so we can see the code better?

Comment: I moved the comments up for you. :D

Comment: I added a comment to the accepted answer that explains the issue better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The Error

The error is telling you that you specified the `file` parameter more than once, which means you likely had one of the following:

- had `file` listed twice in your `$packageArgs`
- have specified `fileType` and `file` and called `Install-ChocolateyPackage`, which only has `filetype` (but PowerShell passes both parameters to `filetype` due to partial parameter name matching)
- passed both `@packageArgs` and `file` as an argument

We've added this issue to https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting.

You may be experiencing other errors now if you've resolved that aspect. See the next section to understand why.

#### The Code

You are trying to pass arguments for [`Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage`](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-install-package), not [`Install-ChocolateyPackage`](https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-package).

If you follow the links you will note the differences that Install-Chocolatey**Install**Package is for locally embedded or UNC share binaries, where Install-ChocolateyPackage is for pulling remote resources.

#### Creating Packages Recommendation

When you create packages, we highly suggest you use `choco new` (from the latest released version of Chocolatey) as it generates the packaging that has documentation of the differences already included in the generated `chocolateyInstall.ps1`. We call this "just in time documentation".

While it appears you did use `choco new` based on your code, I just wanted to add that the latest version will provide the most beneficial documentation regarding creating packages.

Comment: The issue is $file, $fileType, and PowerShell's partial parameter name matching - $file does not exist as a parameter in Install-ChocolateyPackage but $fileType does, so due to PowerShell's partial matching, it wires up both $file and $fileType to -FileType and boom, you get that error.

Comment: Took me a minute to see that there was Install-Chocolatey**Install**Package and ChocolateyPackage

Answer (score 1):

I was installing Redis and faced a similar issue, i managed to solve it by going to an old version [Deprecated], command :

```
choco install redis-64
```

So, the same may work for everyone else by just going to an older version i think.